# Detection of a specific shape in an image

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, opencv

I want to create an algorithm in order to detect the following shape (in the blue region) in videos or images:

[image]

I have no dataset from the corresponding object so I thought that if I define it geometrically, I could use traditional image processing techniques with OpenCV (such as edge detection)to identify it.

Is there more efficient or easier way ?

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution to your question is called Hough Transform, a feature extraction method focusing on shapes. More specific, if you know that you always look for circles, you can use [Circle Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform).

[This link](https://learnopencv.com/hough-transform-with-opencv-c-python/) shows you how to apply it in Python and C.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand Hough transform algorithm is mostly for line and circle detection while I want to detect the whole blue region that I posted above which contains a pi-shaped region with a circle in the center. I read that there is a generalized Hough transform for more complex shapes, maybe this is a solution right ?